# Magento homepage works, displays correctly, but status code is 404

Tags: apache, magento, magento-1.7

I have a very weird issue with my magento CE installation. Homepage works correctly, renders correctly, cookies are set, but status code of the request is 404.
Any other page has status code 200 OK.

Any ideas what is going on? I don't even know what should I check.

Comment: check home is selected as 404 page from admin

Comment: post your site url, so that guess the issues

Comment: lol my homepage was set as no-route = 404 page, thank you @AmitBera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my question is that I removed my homepage, and then it was set to `no-route` because original homepage was gone.